# WPF bindings do not pick up any changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

In my WPF application, I have some properties which I have bound to the XAML counterpart, but for some reason do not get set whenever their values change. I have implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface as well as set my `DataContext` for this View too, and it is still not picking up any changes.

I have this same pattern for other properties within this ViewModel which do work, while others don't.

Here is a snippet of my current code:

### ViewModel

```
public class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string testString;

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        .....
        this.RunCommand = new RelayCommand(this.RunAction);
    }

    public string TestString
    {
        get
        {
            return this.testString;
        }

        set
        {
            this.testString = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("TestString");
        }
    }

    private void RunAction()
    {
        .....
        this.testString = "Running.";
    }
}
```

### View

```
<StatusBarItem>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TestString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" />
</StatusBarItem>
```

### DataContext (set in code-behind of another `MainWindow` class)

```
var testViewModel = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<TestViewModel>();
var testWindow = new TestWindow() { DataContext = testViewModel };
testingWindow.Show();
```

If it helps, this is part of a multi-windowed application which uses MVVM-Light to pass properties between classes.

Comment: what is `ProcessIndicator`?

Comment: sorry. edited to `TestString`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not changing the value of the TestString, you are assigning a command to change the value but you do not seem to be executing it.

```
this.RunCommand = new RelayCommand(this.RunAction);
```

Bind that command to something or execute it manually from somewhere.

Also you need to assign the property not the field

```
this.TestString = "Running.";
```

Comment: ^^ This is the problem - you are assigning to the private member variable and never calling your property setter. Set some breakpoints and use the debug tools and these sort of problems will be much easier to fix. Also consider changing your naming convention - use _testString as your private variable - makes it harder to mix them up.

Comment: Thanks. Simple misunderstanding of how bindings work by the looks of it. As for the command binding, I already have it executing from another element (not included here).

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. You are only updating the private property testString. But you do not update the property TestString so the notify is never called.

Try this:

```
this.TestString = "Running";
```

Comment: Is the method RunAction actually called?

Comment: My changes to my solution are the same as @Janne Matikainen proposed.